# Jenkins installation failed on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: jenkins

jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-06-08 18:47:25 IST; 7min ago
Process: 1966270 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1966270 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 08 18:47:25 sbowork systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 08 18:47:25 sbowork systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Jun 08 18:47:25 sbowork systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Jun 08 18:47:25 sbowork systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 08 18:47:25 sbowork systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 08 18:47:25 sbowork systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.

I have tried all the solutions from google but not luck. Can anybody give me a solution?

Comment: This seems like the end of a `systemctl status jenkins.service` command which doesn't provide the full log. Have a look at the `joutnalctl -u jenkins.service`, you should find more info on your error there.